# CS2061 syntax error in commoncontrols.h

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I have begun writing a little C++ recently, and I decided to write a Qt program as an introduction, since I already know many of the function names etc. I have a file that gets the Jumbo icons using some win32  api. To use this I have the following includes:

```
#include <commoncontrols.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
//other include statements for Qt
```

I keep getting an error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\commoncontrols.h:198: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS'

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\commoncontrols.h:212: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IMAGEINFO'

How could the error be in commoncontrols.h? As I understand it, the compiler cannot find a reference to those `struct`s since CommCtrl is included after commoncontrols. So I reversed their include positions, thinking that would solve the problem, but that caused 127 other errors, so it seems not the correct direction. I am using Qt creator with Qt 5.4.1 and I am on Windows 8.1, so I am using the windows SDK for that. The kit is x64, since I am using the MSVC x64 compiler in VS 2013.

What am I doing wrong and why is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency problem. You didn't provide much information about the other header files.Example;
Header `A.h` might depend on header `B.h` and header `B.h` depend on header `A.h`. 
You mostly solve this problem by replacing `#include "A.h"` in header `B.h` with a forward declaration of header `A.h` like so; `class A` in header `B.h` or vice versa.

Comment: The other headers are all Qt related and don't matter, right? Secondly, both of the header files I am including are part of the Windows SDK. Going in and editing them doesn't seem like a good idea. I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/IronManMark20/c171b429d9b48a2b3435) of my main file.

Comment: try making forward declarations of those windows sdk headers you're including

Comment: @Nana: You **never** have to forward declare anything when using the Windows SDK. While your answer addresses an issue with similar symptoms, the root cause of this question is a different one (I'd assume mismatching preprocessor directives/macros).

Comment: @IInspectable can you look at my source and tell me what is wrong?